# How to delete via SweetAlert in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

I want to delete a row through SweetAlert dialog box. My controller is working fine but I have a problem in JavaScript function. When I click on "Yes delete it", nothing happens. Otherwise it is working when I don't use Javascript.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult DeleteCategory(int id)
{
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        //Get the category
        CategoryDTO dto = db.Categories.Find(id);
        //Remove the category
        db.Categories.Remove(dto);
        //Save
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    //Redirect
    return RedirectToAction("Categories");
}
```

View:

```
<td class="text-center">
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCategory", new { id = item.Id }, new { 
@class = "delete" }) </td>

<script>
$("body").on("click", "a.delete", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure?',
            text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.e) {
                swal(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your category has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                )
            }
        })
    });
<script>
```

Comment: A delete action should never be a GET - its needs to be a POST. You should make a ajax call to call a `[HttpPost]` method if the 'confirm' button is clicked

Comment: @StephenMuecke `[HttpDelete]` is a verb too :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Delete action is working. Well, newbie here. That is why I used class on anchor. A simple alert box is working but I want to delete through sweetAlert dialog box.

Comment: Your changing data - do **NOT** use a GET. Are you wanting to redirect if the record has been successfully deleted, or do you want to stay on the same page (refer [this article](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/4d9083/sweet-alert-with-mvc/) for a typical example)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I want to stay on the same page when record has been successfully deleted.

Comment: I assumed you probably would (but that means that your `return RedirectToAction("Categories");` in the method makes no sense :) -you would need to return a `JsonResult` indicating success or other wise - and if successful, remove the associated record from the DOM. The article I linked gives an example (about 2/3 of the way down)

Answer (score 0):

You are overriding the link onclick.

`e.preventDefault()` stops the event propagating which is stopping the item from being deleted in the same way you were previously which is why if you remove the JS it works.

Having said that you do actually stop propogation and manually call the server after sweetalert confirms that you want it.

inside your then you probably want something like this.

```
           if (result.e) {
                fetch($(this).href()).then(()=>{
                swal(
                    'Deleted!',
                    'Your category has been deleted.',
                    'success'
                )
              }
            }
```

not sure if my getting the href is correct, its been a while since I've done jQuery.

Also as noted in comments GET is a really bad verb to use for deleting something as its unexpected. DELETE is probably best IMO, you will need to read the fetch api docs for how to send a different verb :)

Comment: I changed my verb to [HttpDelete] and still it is not working. Nothing happens when I click on confirm button.

Comment: @HammadAhmed the above code is for a GET request like you currently have. As I've noted you will need to read up on the fetch api to learn about how to pass it a DELETE verb.

Answer (score 0):

By calling prevent default you are stopping the link that is built for you in razor from being called. That means you’ll have to handle that navigation yourself after the confirmation from the user. You’ll want to do something like I’ve outlined below.

```
swal({
 //swal config
})
.then((result) => {
  if (result) {
    // Call deletion logic here - using Ajax

$.ajax({
    type: "DELETE",
    url: '/FakeController/Delete?id=10',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data) {
            // Works
        }
});

 }
});
```

You’ll need to update the url to
match the controller and action you have and you’ll want to change it so you don’t redirect to an action once that delete method gets hit. Also notice the type of Ajax Call is a delete so it will work with your updated attribute type.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I usually use [Ajax Unobtrusive](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/) for deleting an object. Something like the code below:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action link", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    Confirm = "Are you sure?",
    OnBegin = "OnBegin",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccess",
    OnFailure = "OnFailure",
}))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => model.Id)
    <a class="btn btn-warning" title="delete" data-toggle="tooltip" onclick="$(this).parent('form').submit();"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>
}
```

And the script part with be like:

```
function OnBegin() {
    swal({ text: 'Please wait ...' });
}

function OnSuccess() {
    swal({
        title: '',
        text: 'Its Successfully Done!',
        type: 'success',
        confirmButtonText: 'Ok'
    },
        function (isConfirm) {
            if (isConfirm) {
                location.reload(true);
            }
        });
}

function OnFailure() {
    swal({
        title: 'Error',
        text: 'Something happened + error',
        type: 'error',
        confirmButtonText: 'ok'
    });
}
```

Comment: Its a bit pointless to use ajax is you then use `location.reload` to completely refresh the page.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you're right and I really don't ```reload``` the page. it really depends on the view page. it's much better to just remove the element from the page.